# Number of validators in a committee for a particular slot is not equal to the number of aggregation_bits for that committee in the slot

Tags: blocks, consensus, eth-2.0, validators, beacon-chain

I was trying to make a program in which I store the attestations of the validators. But When I started running the program I ran into an error, which was that the number of validators in the committee was not equal to the number of bits in the aggregation_bits.

My process:

1. I am using a Quicknode's api endpoint to get the data
2. I find the validator_index array for all the committees in an epoch
3. I find the aggregation_bits of those committee's and convert that to a binary

for eg: `epoch` = 214606, `slot` = 6867392, `committee_index` = 63 has 323 validators in the validator_array but 328 bits in the aggregation_bits

[image]

[image]

[image]

The validator_array: `["559913","413343","8525","607457","226317","164392","711999","555946","517328","542094","181725","283107","199206","634804","125039","446716","636700","176082","709371","100118","310620","659153","144355","472118","407158","480502","586063","513281","493842","401062","622236","7186","637055","349917","322378","474559","684714","185873","28709","161249","243333","341441","429303","611261","696582","39948","50709","149254","365963","602120","500668","409815","438232","701073","165006","8432","660065","448139","97308","582921","471664","93113","143219","205140","162969","733709","472506","14894","658356","462726","284222","649330","444864","372668","213115","40810","715049","268688","740047","114599","3825","136696","510171","583412","527097","459054","394566","527049","42395","423433","560913","10523","633645","276735","98189","436591","486579","174637","229759","741173","323497","505584","202919","543624","207213","357526","683316","168211","252968","154941","190610","413862","280908","84265","133626","529485","124204","625377","280041","111630","352201","393022","739150","712771","725867","346270","7472","520136","699977","653006","163799","402241","205674","576501","484085","398035","698073","397732","392895","452738","686515","494715","119942","404164","54766","3018","541637","237172","308887","518456","392251","37827","709141","214586","650748","342961","689229","287574","162231","677377","594611","459583","5345","659573","720866","302223","666826","600951","12975","9657","218328","327203","739833","666278","350003","315382","435605","518781","698164","175092","665394","345163","635127","304672","436536","222764","412651","303447","6129","550575","472180","213159","25905","22934","106642","633036","143891","216343","721160","72304","633207","632731","736826","432548","181759","551632","725815","215195","223011","622685","92753","10762","550305","383087","363668","43551","177141","401034","20770","306480","284016","59844","667708","542725","113457","739458","508828","441223","559998","435591","405420","696334","576543","261890","402065","527836","533962","441188","723652","192466","229968","715738","558008","609711","597990","236922","426472","582802","390760","69663","544928","254581","442349","366927","282594","254602","480000","201584","686417","54735","694045","252780","217394","708532","335875","674447","20631","608816","384122","496875","261062","655033","90521","733932","98413","617125","165241","520537","337343","180848","632951","547653","331593","290825","416266","124845","155385","695300","507701","352980","627625","15020","118961","804","535270","276059","69839","196053","633462","10108","323306","409528","57772","567295","190019","306220","585255","341242","119663","98240","729135","663361","254584","275303","328490","337747","197292","302560","270309","712011","631081","478268","400476"]`

Answer (score 1):

The string `0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffeffffffffffffffeffffff7ffffffffff0f` encodes 41 bytes. This in total would give 328 bits as you suggest however the last 4 bits are zero as you can see from `0x0f` that makes 324. Finally you need to remove the last bit which marks the end, which gives 323 as you expect.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying my doubt about this. I have one more question is the first validator would align with the left side or the right side.